# Powershell V3 - Click on Web Page Login Button

Tags: powershell

Powershell noob here, it seems like this should be easy but I can't figure it out.  I'm trying to have my script click on a login button on the home page of a brokerage:

```
$login = Invoke-Webrequest -uri http://www.foliofn.com -sessionvariable fol
$login.links
```

The third link is the login button, which when clicked brings up the login form:

```
innerHTML : <I class=icon-lock></I>Login 
innerText : Login 
outerHTML : <A class="btn btn-small headerloginlink" href="/servlets/ProcessAction?identifier=loginFormEntry&amp;click1=Login"><I class=icon-lock></I>Login </A>
outerText : Login 
tagName   : A
class     : btn btn-small headerloginlink
href      : /servlets/ProcessAction?identifier=loginFormEntry&amp;click1=Login
```

How do I "click" this using the invoke-webrequest method?  Do I need to post somehow (although this is not a form, just a link).

I know I can do it using ie.document.getelementsbyTagName to select this element and then use click(), but I can't figure out how to do it in V3 without using DOM (if that's the right way to say it).

Comment: You could call invoke-request with the uri foliofn.com and append the href of the link/button.

Comment: That's it! Works great and is nice and simple, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the module [AutoBrowse](http://autobrowse.start-automating.com).  It contains commands to make this sort of interaction with IE more scriptable.  Here's a sample of it logging into xbox live.

```
# Autobrowse can make automatically logging into a site simple and easy.  
# This simple pipeline logs someone into xbox (assuming $liveId and $password are set)
$ie = Open-Browser -Url http://xbox.com -Visible|
    Invoke-BrowserControl -Name RpsSignInLink -Click |
    Set-BrowserControl -Name login -Value $liveId | 
    Set-BrowserControl -Name passwd -Value $password | 
    Invoke-BrowserControl -Name SI -Click 

# Once we're in, let's check out recent activity    
$ie | Set-BrowserLocation -Url http://live.xbox.com/en-US/Activity
```